# How can I update my C# project as an executable file/application?

Tags: c#, publish

Every time I click the publish this message appears "the application should not be published to the same folder where the build is produced. please choose a different location for publishing"

Answer (score 0):

You should only publish when you have a version of your application that is ready to go into production. When that time comes, do as the message says and publish to a location that is not the same as where your build output goes because the build output has many files that should NOT be migrated into production environments.

If you just want to compile a new version of the executable for testing purposes, don't Publish, just rebuild.

Without more information from you, this is the best we can advise you.